# css tags are colored with red in wordpress code area

Tags: css, wordpress

[Image of the red tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUlMa.png) I was customizing my wordpress website and suddenly the tags became red and not applied
I disn't know what happened
please help me

I though maybe it was cache problem so I purged the website from all cache and changed the browser but no result

Comment: You need to close off the `span` on line 3. You're missing the closing `}`: `span {`.

Comment: oh thanks my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter a `}` after the first red word.

Comment: thanks so much my friend, I didn't expect that simple shamed mistake because I didn't modify anything there 